# How to write a function which returns an allocated shared memory array in fortran?

Tags: pointers, fortran, mpi, shared-memory

I'd like to create a subroutine which takes an `ALLOCATABLE` array and returns an MPI shared memory array.

I have a bunch of code written in MPI where we use `ALLOCATABLE` arrays.  Now many of these arrays are identical across nodes so storing them in some type of shared memory object would be best.  Now I found this example ([MPI Fortran code: how to share data on node via openMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797298/mpi-fortran-code-how-to-share-data-on-node-via-openmp/41251368)) which works as a standalone code but when I try to implement it as a subroutine I get a Segmentation Fault from the `C_F_POINTER` call.

The driver routine looks like

```
PROGRAM TEST_SUBROUTINE
   ! Libraries
   USE MPI

   IMPLICIT NONE

   ! Variables
   INTEGER :: ier, myid, numprocs
   INTEGER :: myid_shar, numprocs_shar
   INTEGER :: MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, win_a
   DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER :: A(:)

   ! Code
    CALL MPI_INIT(ier)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ier )
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ier)
    myid_shar=0
    CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT_TYPE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, ier)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, myid_shar, ier )
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, numprocs_shar, ier)

    CALL mpialloc_1d_dbl(A,numprocs_shar,myid_shar,0,MPI_COMM_SHARMEM,win_a)

    A(myid_shar+1) = myid_shar
    CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0, win_a, ier)

    IF (myid == 0) THEN
       PRINT *,A(1)
       PRINT *,A(2)
       PRINT *,A(3)
       PRINT *,A(4)
    END IF

    ! FREE Window
    CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0, win_a, ier)
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, ier)
    CALL MPI_WIN_FREE(win_a,ier)

    ! FREE MPI_COMM_SHARMEM
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, ier)
    CALL MPI_COMM_FREE(MPI_COMM_SHARMEM,ier)

    ! END MPI
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ier)
    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ier)

END PROGRAM TEST_SUBROUTINE
```

The subroutine looks like (note I've tried playing with the array variable but without much luck)

```
SUBROUTINE mpialloc_1d_dbl(array,n1,subid,mymaster,share_comm,win)
    ! Libraries
    USE MPI
    USE ISO_C_BINDING

    IMPLICIT NONE

    ! Arguments
    DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER, INTENT(inout) :: array(:)
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n1
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: subid
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: mymaster
    INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: share_comm
    INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: win

    ! Variables
    INTEGER :: disp_unit, ier
    INTEGER :: array_shape(1)
    INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: window_size
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: baseptr

    ier = 0
    array_shape(1) = n1
    disp_unit = 8_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
    window_size = 0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
    IF (subid == mymaster) window_size = INT(n1,MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(share_comm, ier)
    CALL MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED(window_size, disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, share_comm, baseptr, win ,ier)
    IF (subid /= mymaster) CALL MPI_WIN_SHARED_QUERY(win, 0, window_size, disp_unit, baseptr, ier)
    CALL C_F_POINTER(baseptr, array, array_shape)
    CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0, win, ier)

    RETURN

END SUBROUTINE mpialloc_1d_dbl
```

What I'd like to have is a subroutine which behaves similar to a simple `ALLOCATE` statement, returning the shared memory POINTER and the window variables for FENCE calls.

Comment: I'm not sure I even understand why that compiles, let alone a seg faults - Array should have the pointer attribute to be used in C_F_POINTER. And you really should use the kind values from iso_c_binding to ensure interoperability, and anyway Double Precision is so 1980s

Comment: It compiles (Intel compiler on the Knightslanding architecture), turns out my pseudo code works fine but my actual code has the Segmentation Fault.  I'm going to do some more digging.

Comment: The pseudo-code fails to compile with gfortran 7.4.0: Error: Argument FPTR at (1) to C_F_POINTER must be a pointer

Comment: If you give it the `POINTER` attribute does it compile then?

Comment: Yes - I suggest you include that in your own code and edit the question as appropriate

Comment: So I tried switching to `DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER, INTENT(inout) :: array(:)` and end up getting an error at compile time complaining that I'm not passing a `POINTER` from the calling code.

Comment: Last comment - you have to sort out your question before we go further: DOUBLE PRECISION, INTENT(inout) :: array(:) is what the code in the question above currently says, and what is failing to compiler for me!

Comment: Sorry, was a typo.  I've edited the comment.

Comment: But for clarification, if I change both the calling function and the subroutine deffinitions from `ALLOCATABLE` to `POINTER` the code compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK so the error here has to do with calling Fortran 90 style subroutines.  See this link for a partial explanation (http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~szymansk/OOF90/bugs.html#8)  Now in the above example I'd actually just put the subroutine at the end of the program.  This has the effect of acting as an implicit interface statement (at least in with GFORTRAN and INTEL compilers).  So my Pseudo-code worked fine, however in my production code the subroutine added as part of a general use library that many other pieces of code called.  If I linked my Pseudo-code to this library which was a copy-paste of the subroutine in the Pseudo-code, the code would crash as in the production code.  However, if I added an `INTERFACE` block everything worked fine.

So where does that leave me?  Well for 'reasons' I didn't want to write yet another specialized module but it seems as if I will have to anyway and put all the various shared memory subroutines in it.  The other option is to add interface blocks to every bit of shared memory allocating sub code (blagh).

Here's the fixed code, but you need to compile the subroutine and program seperately and link to see the effect of having / not having the `INTERFACE` block.

**Main program:**

```
PROGRAM TEST_SUBROUTINE
   ! Libraries
   USE MPI

   IMPLICIT NONE

   INTERFACE
      SUBROUTINE mpialloc_1d_dbl(array,n1,subid,mymaster,share_comm,win)
      DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER, INTENT(inout) :: array(:)
      INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n1
      INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: subid
      INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: mymaster
      INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: share_comm
      INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: win
      END SUBROUTINE mpialloc_1d_dbl
   END INTERFACE

   ! Variables
   INTEGER :: ier, myid, numprocs
   INTEGER :: myid_shar, numprocs_shar
   INTEGER :: MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, win_a
   DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER :: A(:)

   ! Code
    CALL MPI_INIT(ier)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_WORLD, myid, ier )
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_WORLD, numprocs, ier)
    myid_shar=0
    CALL MPI_COMM_SPLIT_TYPE(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0, MPI_INFO_NULL, MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, ier)
    CALL MPI_COMM_RANK( MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, myid_shar, ier )
    CALL MPI_COMM_SIZE( MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, numprocs_shar, ier)

    CALL mpialloc_1d_dbl(A,numprocs_shar,myid_shar,0,MPI_COMM_SHARMEM,win_a)

    A(myid_shar+1) = myid_shar
    CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0, win_a, ier)

    IF (myid == 0) THEN
       PRINT *,A(1)
       PRINT *,A(2)
       PRINT *,A(3)
       PRINT *,A(4)
    END IF

    ! FREE Window
    CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0, win_a, ier)
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, ier)
    CALL MPI_WIN_FREE(win_a,ier)

    ! FREE MPI_COMM_SHARMEM
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_SHARMEM, ier)
    CALL MPI_COMM_FREE(MPI_COMM_SHARMEM,ier)

    ! END MPI
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(MPI_COMM_WORLD, ier)
    CALL MPI_FINALIZE(ier)

END PROGRAM TEST_SUBROUTINE
```

**Subroutine:**

```
SUBROUTINE mpialloc_1d_dbl(array,n1,subid,mymaster,share_comm,win)
    ! Libraries
    USE MPI
    USE ISO_C_BINDING

    IMPLICIT NONE

    ! Arguments
    DOUBLE PRECISION, POINTER, INTENT(inout) :: array(:)
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: n1
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: subid
    INTEGER, INTENT(in) :: mymaster
    INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: share_comm
    INTEGER, INTENT(inout) :: win

    ! Variables
    INTEGER :: disp_unit, ier
    INTEGER :: array_shape(1)
    INTEGER(KIND=MPI_ADDRESS_KIND) :: window_size
    TYPE(C_PTR) :: baseptr

    ier = 0
    array_shape(1) = n1
    disp_unit = 8_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
    window_size = 0_MPI_ADDRESS_KIND
    IF (subid == mymaster) window_size = INT(n1,MPI_ADDRESS_KIND)
    CALL MPI_BARRIER(share_comm, ier)
    CALL MPI_WIN_ALLOCATE_SHARED(window_size, disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, share_comm, baseptr, win ,ier)
    IF (subid /= mymaster) CALL MPI_WIN_SHARED_QUERY(win, 0, window_size, disp_unit, baseptr, ier)
    CALL C_F_POINTER(baseptr, array, array_shape)
    CALL MPI_WIN_FENCE(0, win, ier)

    RETURN

END SUBROUTINE mpialloc_1d_dbl
```