# Making all processors in a computing node read the same memory block in OpenMPI

Tags: c, mpi, cluster-computing

I want to run a numerical simulation in a computing cluster using OpenMPI and C. However, there is a big matrix `A` that is constant and equal in every proccessor. To avoid alloc'ing too much unnecessary memory, I want to group the processors that have a shared memory (that is, they are in the same computing node) and have only one processor in each node malloc and set that big matrix `A`. Then all other processors in the node should be able to read that matrix.

[This other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24797298/mpi-fortran-code-how-to-share-data-on-node-via-openmp) is exactly what I need, but it is in Fortran. I took its answer and made a prototype in C, but it is not working as expected. For a reason I can not understand, the memory address returned by `MPI_Win_allocate_shared` is offset by 1 displacement unit. See code below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mpi.h>

int
main ()
{
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);
    int num_processors;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_processors);
    int proc_global_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &proc_global_rank);

    // Split de global communicator, grouping by shared memory
    MPI_Comm compute_comm;
    MPI_Comm_split_type(MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_COMM_TYPE_SHARED, 0, MPI_INFO_NULL, &compute_comm);
    int proc_compute_rank;
    MPI_Comm_rank(compute_comm, &proc_compute_rank);

    // Create the window
    const int ARRAY_SIZE = 1;
    int* shared_data;
    MPI_Aint shared_data_size;
    if (proc_compute_rank == 0) {
        shared_data_size = ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(int);
    } else {
        shared_data_size = 0;
    }
    int disp_unit = sizeof(int);
    MPI_Win window;
    MPI_Win_allocate_shared(shared_data_size, disp_unit, MPI_INFO_NULL, compute_comm, &shared_data, &window);
    if (proc_compute_rank == 0) {
        shared_data[0] = -10;
    }
    // get the location of the shared memory segment
    if (proc_compute_rank != 0) {
        MPI_Win_shared_query(window, 0, &shared_data_size, &disp_unit, shared_data);
    }
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);  // wait for shared variables to be ready to be used
    MPI_Barrier(compute_comm);
    printf("rank %d, value[0] = %d\n", proc_compute_rank, shared_data[0]);  // prints a wrong value
    printf("rank %d, value[-1] = %d\n", proc_compute_rank, shared_data[-1]);  // prints correct value
    // do calculations...
    MPI_Win_fence(0, window);  // wait for shared variables to be no longer needed
    MPI_Barrier(compute_comm);
    MPI_Win_free(&window);
    MPI_Finalize();
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: It looks ok to me. What is it printing out?

Comment: the first process prints the expected -10, but all the others processors print the same, random value, but with different pointer addresses.

Comment: Wild guess: you have the "separate memory model" so you need to use `MPI_Put` to put the value in the window at proc 0. `int *modelstar,flag;
  MPI_Win_get_attr(the_window,MPI_WIN_MODEL,&modelstar,&flag);
  int model = *modelstar;
  if (procno==0)
    printf("Window model is unified: %d\n",model==MPI_WIN_UNIFIED);`

Comment: I made an edit to the question. The pointer returned by `MPI_Win_shared_query` is offset by +1 unit. Using `MPI_Put` has the same results.

Comment: The final argument of `query` needs an extra ampersand. Also, getting the `[-1]` data makes no sense.

Comment: Yes, the missing `&` is what was wrong. `query` expects the *value of the pointer* to change it, not the value pointed by it. Would you make an answer for me to accept it?

Comment: Done. Please note an added note about the addresses you see.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The real problem in your code is that you pass an `int*` to `MPI_Win_query`, but that call needs to set the pointer, so you need to pass an `int**`, meaning in your case `&shared_data`.

There can potentially be a second problem: by setting the contents of the window buffer explicitly you are assuming the "unified memory model", which is likely the case. If in doubt, test

```
MPI_Win_get_attr(the_window,MPI_WIN_MODEL,&modelstar,&flag);
```

and make sure that that parameter is not `MPI_WIN_SEPARATE`, in which case you'd have to `MPI_Put` the data into the window.

Btw, you made an observation about the processes getting different addresses. That is going to stay true even after you fix your ampersand error! What a programmer thinks of as an address is only a *logical address* which is translated by the "page table" into a *physical address*. But every process has its own page table, so the same physical address will translate to different logical addresses ni the processes, and so, yes, you will get different printed hex addresses, even if you have the right pointer.